# only last uitableview cell is correct, rest show null items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Basically I am following this tutorial: http://thedarkdev.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/web-service-apps-in-ios7-json-with.html and for some reason the last cell displays the correct information but the previous ones only display the title:

[image: screenshot of ios app]

Also, the output in the console window shows the information information for the author. So for some reason its not being pulled into the other cells.

Here is the .m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *myObject;
    // A dictionary object
    NSDictionary *dictionary;
    // Define keys
    NSString *title;
    NSString *thumbnail;
    NSString *author;
    NSString *permalink;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    title = @"title";
    thumbnail = @"thumbnail";
    author = @"author";
    permalink = @"permalink";

    myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                      [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ios-blog.co.uk/?feed=json"]];

    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                  jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
        NSString *title_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *thumbnail_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
        NSString *author_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"author"];
        NSString *permalink_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"permalink"];

        NSLog(@"TITLE: %@",title_data);
        NSLog(@"THUMBNAIL: %@",thumbnail_data);
        NSLog(@"AUTHOR: %@",author_data);
        NSLog(@"URL: %@",permalink_data);

        dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  title_data, title,
                  thumbnail_data, thumbnail,
                  author_data,author,
                  permalink_data,permalink,
                  nil];
        [myObject addObject:dictionary];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     return myObject.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Item";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
          UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSMutableString *text;
    //text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKey:title]];
    text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
            [tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:title]];

    NSMutableString *detail;
detail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Author: %@ ",
          [tmpDict objectForKey:author]];

    NSMutableString *images;
    images = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",
              [tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];

    cell.textLabel.text = text;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= detail;
    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 70);
    cell.imageView.image =img;

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"URL: %@", [[myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:permalink]);

    NSString* launchUrl = (@"%@", [[myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:permalink]);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: launchUrl]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

any ideas why and how to fix this? Thanks in advance :)

Edit: After solving this solution thanks to the answer provided by: Martin R: **How can I provide default values if any of the dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys values are nil?**

Comment: Why `NSMutableString`?

Comment: i think that you can directly do: cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tmpDict objectForKey: author];

Comment: @Larme Following the tutorial

Comment: @Ilario - nope, that doesn't output anything, not even (null)

Comment: are you sure? have you tried that? strange.. i use almost the same code but not NSMutableString and pass value directly in detailText

Comment: Can you confirm if you get correct output in the console for `[tmpDict objectForKey:author]` inside  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: yup there is an output in the console

Comment: if there is an output, why you can't  pass [tmpDict objectForKey:author] to cell.detailText.text ?

Comment: I have no idea. As I said i'm following the tutorial listed above and the code supplied is the full .h files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          title_data, title,
                          thumbnail_data, thumbnail,
                          author_data,author,
                          permalink_data,permalink,
                          nil];
```

Many objects in your JSON array have no "thumbnail" entry, and `thumbnail_data` is `nil`.

But `nil` acts as a *terminator* for `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:`,
therefore the following keys "author" and "permalink" are ignored.

There are various ways to solve this problem. For example, you could
use `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:` instead of `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:`:

```
for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [dataDict dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:@[title, thumbnail, author, permalink]];
    [myObject addObject:dictionary];
}
```

This method substitutes `NSNull` values for `nil` values (and it is less code).

Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you check if the value is `NSNull` or not:

```
NSDictionary *tmpDict = dataDict[indexPath.row];
NSString *thumbnailURL = tmpDict[thumbnail];
UIImage *img;
if ([thumbnailURL isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultImage.png"];
} else {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
}
```

Comment: Awesome, How would I go about using a default thumbnail if there isn't one specified. Sorry, i'm a beginner.

Comment: i think that solving this, you can directly do: cell.detailText.text = [tmpDic objectForKey: author]; right?

Comment: @Ilario: You can do that, but the problem occurs earlier.

Comment: @MartinR Ive added those into the code and there are build errors, I've tried adding them around also. Can you show me where they should go with example. Sorry i am new to Obj-C and struggling a little.

Comment: @MarkP: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/21e575278a454e854537. I have also renamed some variables. That does compile, but I did not run the code. Hope it helps!